# PowerShell Register-ScheduledJob cmdlet - Set "Run Only When User Is Logged In" & -WindowStyle Maximized

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-5.0

I want to set these two options for a dynamically-created scheduled job,
Going through the PowerShell documentation, I couldn't find any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Register-ScheduledJob` is having a parameter `-Filepath`, you can pass the script as an argument for this parameter and have another parameter `-Argument`, pass "-WindowsStyle Maximized" as an argument for this parameter.

```
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath <script.ps1> -Argument '-WindowStyle Maximized'
```

Regards,

kvprasoon

Answer (score 0):

The [Register-ScheduledJob](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223922) has a `Trigger` parameter:

> The Trigger parameter of Register-ScheduledJob adds one or more job
>   triggers that start the job.

So you have to define a trigger for you job using the [New-JobTrigger](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223912) cmdlet:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
```

And pass it to your job.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't cover the window maximized, does it?

Comment: Following a test I've made it doesn't change the "run only when user is logged on" property, as requested, so this does not answer my question

Comment: "Starts the scheduled job when the specified users log on to the computer. To specify a user, use the User parameter." - Source: New-JobTrigger documentation. This is the only way I know to specify the trigger.